# Variables in Webapp2

Tags: python, ide, webapp2

I am currently learning Python and WebApp2 using Codenvy IDE.

I currently have simple code that load very basic HTML. Everything works fine. Until I try to add a variable (named myvariable) and try to assign it some value. Once I add that line, I get a page saying:

"Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds."

```
import webapp2

MAIN_PAGE_HTML = """tons of html code that works"""

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

#problem is when I add this line:
        myvariable = "photo"
#everything load correctly when it is not there. 

    self.response.write(MAIN_PAGE_HTML)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

Why adding a variable that does nothing bug everything? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show your actual code with the correct indentation.

Comment: It is the current code and I figured out due to your comment that indeed, the problem was the indentation! Didn't know it mattered!